Does the reproducing property of the unitary group Poisson kernel require a multiple of the identity?
The Poisson kernel of the unitary group is
$$ P(Z,U)=\frac{\det(1-ZZ^\dagger)^N}{\det(1-ZU^\dagger)^N\det(1-UZ^\dagger)^N}.$$
It has a reproducing property, $\int dU P(Z,U)f(U)=f(Z)$, where $dU$ is the invariant measure. One way to prove this is using Schur functions. If $Z$ happens to be a multiple of the identity, $Z=a1_N$, then
$$\frac{1}{\det(1-aU^\dagger)^N}=\sum_\lambda a^{|\lambda|}s_\lambda(1_N)s_\lambda(U^\dagger).$$
Then, assuming $\frac{f(U)}{\det(1-\bar{a}U)^N}$ also has a Schur series, orthogonality $\int dU s_\lambda(U^\dagger)s_\mu(U)=\delta_{\lambda\mu}$ gives the result. It seems to me essential to assume $Z=a1_N$ for this calculation to work.
On the other hand, the poisson kernel is the pushforward of the invariant measure under action of linear fractional transforms $U\mapsto (U+Z)(1_N-Z^\dagger U)^{-1}$. So  $\int dU P(Z,U)f(U)$ should be equal to $\int dU f[(U+Z)(1_N-Z^\dagger U)^{-1}]$. By expanding this integrand in a Schur series, the integral equals the constant term, $f(Z)$. But in this calculation the condition $Z=a1_N$ is not required.

a comment motivated by Poisson kernel for the orthogonal groups; the Poisson kernel for the unitary group ${\rm U}(N)$ has the reproducing property for any sub-unitary $Z$; for the special orthogonal group ${\rm SO}(2N)$ the generalised Poisson kernel from arXiv:0902.2164 only has the reproducing property for $Z$ proportional to the unit matrix, so in that case the restriction $Z=aI$ seems to be essential; I do not know if it can be relaxed.

The reproducing property of the Poisson kernel holds for any sub-unitary $Z$. This is a result of Hua [1]. A modern derivation (by means of an expansion in terms of Jack polynomials) is in Random matrix ensembles with an effective extensive external charge.
[1] L.K. Hua, Analysis of Functions of Several Complex Variables in the Classical Domains (1963)

As an addendum, let me add a proof of the reproducing property based on a result from scattering theory due to Brouwer [2]. The scattering geometry is shown in the figure:

It is composed of two scattering matrices in series, a deterministic scattering matrix $S_1$ of the barrier (black rectangle) and a random scattering matrix $S_0$ of the dotted circle.
Brouwer shows that if the matrix $S_0$ is uniformly distributed with the Haar measure in ${\rm U}(N)$, then the full scattering matrix $U$ of the combined system is distributed according to the Poisson kernel $P(Z,U)$, with $Z$ the reflection sub-matrix of $S_1=\begin{pmatrix}Z&T\\ T'&Z'\end{pmatrix}$.
The matrix $U$ can be decomposed into partial scattering sequences,
$$U=Z+TS_0T'+TS_0Z'S_0T'+\cdots$$
Because of the invariance $d\mu(S_0)=d\mu(e^{i\phi}S_0)$ of the Haar measure, the average over the unitary group of arbitrary powers $p=1,2,3\ldots$ of $S_0$ vanishes, $\langle S_0M_1S_0M_2\cdots S_0M_p\rangle=0$ hence $\langle U^p\rangle=Z^p$. If $f(U)$ is analytic, so it can be expanded in a power series in $U$, the reproducing property then follows,
$$\langle f(U)\rangle=\langle f(Z)\rangle.$$
Note that the matrix $Z$ can be any sub-unitary matrix.
[2] P.W. Brouwer, Generalized circular ensemble of scattering matrices for a chaotic cavity with non-ideal leads (1995).

Thanks. In the "modern" paper they also must assume $Z$ is a multiple of the identity when doing the Jack expansion. So this seems to be a real limitation of this method, which is a bit curious. I would love to get a comment about this from the symmetric function experts.
